# Why does Aptana (eclipse) create duplicate python packages/files?

Tags: python, eclipse, file, aptana, duplication

A picture says more then thousand words:

[image: A part of my project explorer in Aptana/Eclipse.]

I created **one** src foulder and **one** webscraper folder with **one** file named dblp.py in it. Why is Aptana/Eclipse showing the duplicates?

Comment: If you refresh the src folder does it display correctly?

Comment: @sdolan: I played a little with Aptanas erspectives and I found out, that I was in the **web**perspective, I changed to the **python**perspective and now there are no duplicates anymore. But changing back to the **web**perspective the duplicates are shown again. Perhaps it is meant to be this way,... I don't know. :-)

Comment: Seems to me like a bug in aptana... maybe search the bug reports?  Create a new one if you can't find anything.

Comment: I opened a discussion on the aptana website. Thanks for feedback, @sdolan.

Comment: maybe it's because of *.pyc files?

Comment: @sdolan: Your guess turned out right. aptana confirms, that it is a bug.

Comment: @Druss: Sure seemed like a bug :)  Can you post a link to the bug description for future viewers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround is to click on the drop-down arrow in Project Explorer and select Customize View...; then in the new dialog, switch to Content tab and uncheck the Local Filesystem entry.